# C++ std::string internal memory handling

Tags: c++, string, memory-leaks

I am confused with how std::string handles it's copied(?) memory.

When I try to do that:

```
char* abc = new abc[512];
abc = "abcdef";
std::string tempstr(abc);
tempstr[0] = 'Y';
std::cout << tempstr.c_str() << std::endl;
std::cout << abc << std::endl;
```

I get the following output:

```
Ybcdef
abcdef
```

But if I try to free memory allocated by *new*, by adding this at the end:

```
delete [] abc;
```

I am getting a memory error (_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID)
Now my question is, how is this possible? String seems to copy abc's data, leaving it untouched, yet I, for some reason, cannot delete it.

I am asking this, because I have the following situation in my code:

```
char* somestring = new char[1024];
// something happens to somestring here
stack.push_back(somestring); // stack is a vector of strings
```

And I am wondering where should I free memory allocated by somestring.

Comment: You're trying to delete a string literal. `new` is extremely unnecessary here.

Comment: `abc = "abcdef";` will not do what you think... It reassigns a pointer, it does **not** write the characters into the previously allocated memory.

Comment: No, this **cannot possibly** be **that** hard to grasp... No, no, no, I've understood this the very first time I've read it. Read through that beginners' C++ tutorial once again and *please* don't clutter SO with dupes.

Answer (score 6):

```
char* abc = new abc[512];
abc = "abcdef";
```

With these two statements you just caused a memory leak, and `abc` does not point to dynamic memory anymore but it points to a string literal placed in read only memory. So when you call:

```
delete [] abc;
```

You are actually calling `delete` on a pointer which does not point to dynamically allocated memory, this results in **undefined behavior** & potentially a segmentation fault.

```
abc = "abcdef";
```

does not copy the string to memory allocated to `abc` but it simply reseats `abc` to point to a string literal. To be able to copy the string to memory allocated for `abc` you need to use `std::copy` or `strncpy`.

Answer (score 3):

```
char* abc = new abc[512];

       +-----------------------+
abs -> | 512 byte memory block |
       +-----------------------+


abc = "abcdef";

       +-----------------------+
       | 512 byte memory block |
       +-----------------------+

       +----------+
abs -> | abcdef\0 |
       +----------+


std::string tempstr(abc);

       +-----------------------+
       | 512 byte memory block |
       +-----------------------+

       +----------+
abs -> | abcdef\0 |
       +----------+

                +----------+
temp.c_str() -> | abcdef\0 |
                +----------+


tempstr[0] = 'Y';

       +-----------------------+
       | 512 byte memory block |
       +-----------------------+

       +----------+
abs -> | abcdef\0 |
       +----------+

                +----------+
temp.c_str() -> | Ybcdef\0 |
                +----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not deleting through the pointer you've allocated and your program has undefined behaviour.

```
abc = "abcdef";
```

`abc` now points to the beggining of the string literal of *static* storage duration. You're not allowed to modify it or delete it. The original pointer, it's lost and you leaked the memory you allocated.

What you could (and what I think you wanted) to do:

```
char* abc = new abc[512];
const char* s = "abcdef"; // note the const - assigning a pointer to string literal to 
                          // char* is illegal in C++11
std::copy(s, s+6, abc);
```

Any yes, `std::string` owns the content of the string, it copies it from `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't allocate the memory pointed to by `abc`: it is coming from a string literal. Thus, you are not allowed to delete the memory or modify the content in any way. When an `std::string` is constructed from a string literal, it creates a copy of the string literal and maintains the memory needed for this copy internally.